# DataValidation Dropdown with multiple criteria in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

1. I have a table of groups.
2. I'm searching for a way so that "Group 2" will get updated when "Group 1" changes.

[image]

Please note that

- I want this without any Script or HelperColumn.
- I don't want to use Named Ranged in dropdown criteria.
  (a named range would work, if it automatically read the name from the left side cell containing the dynamic name of Group 1)

Thanks in advance.

Sample File:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PowepsBJLymzZSr6ODR_Gxioxvn3WDDYGctwZVHbvqg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please share a link to the sheet in the screesnhot with EDIT access. If you don't want to expose your email [make an anonymous sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) and copy the data there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but all your final limitations are all the ways that this can be done

Comment: @Martín thanks. what about having a dynamic definition of named range, so that in the dropdown range, we put =indirect(X) and X=the named range based on the left side cell (selected group 1). I tried =indirect(B2) but it raised an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It would be fantastic and solve a lot of scenarios, but it's not possible right now